# How to loop over datetime range in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to loop from current date to xxx date in columns
I'm thinking about using this function:

```js
from datetime import timedelta, date


def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    start_date = datetime.date.today()
    end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)



for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    print single_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

But I don't know how to pass it to context in views.py

I want something like this, but in days:

[image]

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it using custom template tag:

Firstly create the file structure. Go into the app directory where the tag is needed, and add these files:

> templatetags
>
> templatetags/**init**.py
>
> templatetags/custom_tags.py

The templatetags/custom_tags.py file:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.daterange
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    start_date = datetime.date.today()
    end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)
```

The template part:

```
{% load custom_tags%}


{%for date_out in start_date|daterange:timedelta %}
   <!-- do something here with date_out -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I got:

`TemplateSyntaxError at /alocation/
'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for date_out in daterange start_date timedelta`

I think the problem is here `daterange start_date timedelta` and for django template it is too complicated.

Comment: @HereHere , try the updated answer , I fixed the **for** loop and the **@register** statement  before the function definition

Comment: Unfortunately, I got `'Library' object has no attribute 'daterange'`

Comment: try **register.filter('daterange', daterange)** after the function definition instead of  **@register.daterange**

Comment: And make sure to put templatetags folder in the root directory of your django app beside models.py , views.py , ....etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80302/discussion-between-amr-abdelaziz-and-herehere).

Answer (score 1):

I got another way to do it:

Just use pass this function to context `'daterange': daterange()`

```
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    start_date = datetime.date.today()
    end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)
```

and in your template:

```
{% for i in date_range %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `{% for i in daterange %}`?